# How to improve the WinForms performance when disabling a form?

Tags: winforms, performance

Calling this.Enabled = false in a form takes between 140 and 170 ms in our development systems. Many computers from our customers are slower.

Our system works with many different forms. Usually the user sees a list of items and does a double-click on one of them. The system disables the current form, reads the data from our server asynchronly (this is the reason for disabling the form) and when the data arrives it displays the new form for editting it. When the user is ready, he closes the current form and the system enables the previous one.

The 170 ms look really bad when you compare with the total times our system takes to open the new form.

These are typical times:

- Disabling the current form: 170 ms
- Getting the data from the server: 400 ms
- Displaying the new form: 200 ms

Getting the data means accesing a remote server, the server reads the information from a database executing between 5 and 20 queries and returns the data. It is difficult to explain that disabling a form takes nearly 25% of the whole time.

Is there a way of improving the time for disabling a form? Alternatively, what could I do to avoid that my customers click around or use the current form until the information is loaded and the next one is shown?

**Update:**
I didn't mention it, but I did a test using just standard controls and no logic at all. The form is a little bit complex (but nothing crazy). It uses a tabcontrol with 3 tabs and in every tab I added different controls (picturebox, textboxes, comboboxes, listboxes, etc) for a total of around 30 controls in the tab. I press a button and then I do a this.Enabled = false in the form. This is taking between 100 and 120 ms. Our software is more complex and it takes around 170 ms.

**Update 2:**
I found the explanation. The test were done in a laptop and the energy profile was set to balanced instead of high performance (I don't know if these are the right names in english). The disabled command takes around 100 ms with the balanced profile and 20 ms with the high performance. This is quite a big difference as the laptop was working connected to the power supply and not on batteries.

Comment: No repro, of course. It doesn't take anywhere near that long to disable a form on my system. You'll need to post code that demonstrates the problem. There is something unique about your application, it does little good for us to guess about what it might be.

Comment: Ok, sorry. I didn't mention it, but I did a test using just standard controls and no logic at all. The form is a little bit complex (but nothing crazy). It uses a tabcontrol with 3 tabs and in every tab I added different controls (picturebox, textboxes, comboboxes, listboxes, etc) for a total of around 30 controls in the tab. I press a button and then I do a this.Enabled = false in the form. This is taking between 100 and 120 ms. Our software is more complex and it takes around 170 ms.

Answer (score 0):

I found the explanation. The test were done in a laptop and the energy profile was set to balanced instead of high performance (I don't know if these are the right names in english). The Disabled=false command takes around 100 ms with the balanced profile and 20 ms with the high performance. This is quite a big difference as the laptop was working connected to the power supply and not on batteries.

Comment: How are you timing this? Chances are, it is the timer's resolution that is appearing to affect your results. Allowing a computer with power management capabilities to dynamically suspend is going to wreak havoc on any timing attempts. It won't necessarily make the application run slower, though.